# How can I configure Emacs to search verbatim by default?

Tags: init-file, search

Emacs makes assumptions about what constitutes an adequate match for a search.  In particular, AFAICT, it disregards whitespace differences, as well as differences in case.

*During an incremental search*, it is possible to toggle these settings.  For example, `M-s SPC` toggles whitespace matching.

But is there something I can put in my `.emacs` file such that the default initial settings are the strict ones?  (I.e. search for the exact string I have typed in the minibuffer.)

Just to be clear, I still want to be able to toggle these settings.  (In fact, my preference would be to selectively adjust these settings for the duration of a search, rather than turning them on or off for the remainder of the session.)

Comment: `C-h k C-s` says this: *In incremental searches, a space or spaces normally matches any whitespace
defined by the variable `search-whitespace-regexp`; see also the variables
`isearch-lax-whitespace` and `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace`.* Setting these variables in your `.emacs` should change defaults. (Whenever I want to customize an Emacs feature, I use `C-h k`, `C-h f`, and `C-h v` to learn more about it. Most of the time it works very well.)

Comment: @Constantine: Actually, this suggestion works for whitespace, but not for case-fold, and not just because the documentation for `C-s` says nothing about it.  I find that (1) whereas `M-s SPC` has a persistent effect on how whitespace is handled in searches, the effect of `M-s c` lasts only for the duration of the search; and (2) the search is initially case insensitive irrespecitve of the value I assign to the variable `isearch-case-fold-search`.  I've tested this in an Emacs session that I started with `emacs -Q -l /dev/null`, so I don't think it's due to some weird config.  (v24.4.1, Debian)

Comment: @Constantine: OK, I get it.  Even though the variable `isearch-case-fold-search` does exist, despite its name, it is not really the counterpart of `isearch-lax-whitespace` with respect to case-fold.  That variable is `case-fold-search`.

Comment: Do you mind summarizing what worked for you in an answer? (Assuming that you have a solution.) Thanks!

Comment: @Constantine: done

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally put in my .emacs

```
(setq isearch-lax-whitespace nil)
(setq isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace nil)

;; the next setting affects both isearch-* and isearch-*-regexp; also, according
;; to its documentation it "[a]utomatically becomes buffer-local when set";
;; therefore, `(setq-default case-fold-search nil)` won't do.
(setq-default case-fold-search nil)
```

I can still toggle the white-space and case-fold settings during a search, with `M-s SPC` and `M-s c`, respectively, but I never figured out how to change either of these settings only for the duration of the search.

Thanks to Constantine for the pointers.